# Legitimacy of using assumptions of a previously proven conditional in a biconditional proof

Tags: logic

I am working on Velleman's How to Prove it, and I am asked to prove:

For every integer n, 6|n iff 2|n and 3|n. In logical form, that is: $$\forall n\in Z(6|n\leftrightarrow(2|n \land3|n))  $$

Where a|b means there is some integer m such that ma=b.

Velleman first proved the conditional from left to right. Assuming 6|n, he used existential instantiation on its logical form:
$$\exists k\in Z(6k=n)$$
...to get 6k=n. (I was taught that to use the EI rule you must not instantiate it to a previously seen variable, i.e. k, but this is not my biggest problem with it)

As for the conclusion 2|n:
$$\exists j\in Z(2j=n)$$
He wants to find an integer j such that 2j=n. He then observes that 6k=n gives us 2(3k)=n, which is a good substitute for j such that j=3k, and that it is also an integer, thus proving 2|n. (He didn't bother to prove 3|n)

When he tries to prove the conditional from right to left, that's where my confusion begins, where he assumes 2|n and 3|n to prove 6|n. All of a sudden, he observes that $$ 6(j-k)=6j-6k=3(2j)-2(3k)=3n-2n=n $$And that since j-k is an integer, this gives us 6|n.

But this is only possible, it seems to me, if he assumes 2j=n and 3k=j. BUT those are assumptions from the proof of the left to right conditional! Shouldn't those have been discharged already? Why is legitimate to recycle assumptions from a proven conditional?

Comment: The right to left argument is entirely separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By switching the direction of the implication, he is essentially starting an entirely new proof. Thus, in a sense, the new $j$ and $k$ are different. But in order to ease understanding, he borrows the notation from the earlier part of the proof, separate but similar. This way the variables are familiar and their properties clear. He is certainly glazing over some nit-picky aspects, but so long as the idea of the proof is well conveyed, that is okay.